# Link fix in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I'm using the following code to link between pages

```
<Link to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              search: redirect
            }}>Login</Link>
```

When I try to link, the link comes out as `localhost:8000/[Object Object]`. Am I using Link properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Link to="/login" />` expects a string. You are passing an object which is not a viable option. See the Reach Router [documentation](https://reach.tech/router/api/Link) which Gatsby implements as Gatsby Link.

You can pass a state for `search: redirect`. Here the example from the reach router documentation:

```
const NewsFeed = () => (
  <div>
    <Link
      to="photos/123"
      state={{ fromNewsFeed: true }}
    />
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're passing an object to the `to` property. It must be a string indicating the route you intend to navigate to.

Try:

```js
<Link to="/login">Login</Link>
```

Check out the [Gatbsy Link API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/) for more information about its properties.